# Loop in phpmyadmin don't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to make loop in MySQL, but it always shows me an error.

Is it correct code or did I make a mistake?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    test_loop : LOOP
       IF (int_val = 10) THEN
          LEAVE test_loop;
       END IF;
       SET int_val = int_val +1;
       SELECT int_val; 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: please credit those that help you by clicking the check mark next to their answer.

Comment: add a delimiter with command DELIMITER

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the default delimiter is `;` and stops the execution/parsing of the procedure code. Change the delimiter before you create the procedure and set it back to `;` after the procedure code like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop_test;

DELIMITER #

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
    ...
END #

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Still same error :
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 12 


Code :
`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop_test;
DELIMITER #

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    test_loop : LOOP
       IF (int_val = 10) THEN
          LEAVE test_loop;
       END IF;
       SET int_val = int_val +1;
       SELECT int_val; 
    END LOOP; 
END #
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I tried executing your code and it is working for me. I have to disappoint you that I have no answer to your error message.